# I'm looking for answer to z^e = -1

Tags: complex-numbers

Anyone have anything? I'm writing a "proof" for something and it came up. I'm stupid (as username suggests) and it would take way too long for me to solve it, and I wouldn't want to delete it since I want to just write QED in place of the proof for the solution

Comment: $$z\in\left\{\exp\left(\frac{2n+1}{e}\pi i\right):n\in\Bbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Your post is a bare problem statement without any context, which might attract down votes and close votes. To avoid this, take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) and on [avoiding "I'm stupid" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: write -1 as a complex exponential $e^{(2n+1)i\pi}$ and take the $\frac{1}{e}$ power.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you will have to know the exponential form of a complex number.
If $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $z \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$\large
z = \cos(\theta + 2k\pi) + i\sin(\theta + 2k\pi) = e^{(\theta + 2k\pi)i}
$$
You can write $-1$ like this,
$$\large
-1 = \cos(\pi + 2k\pi) + i\sin(\pi + 2k\pi) = e^{(\pi + 2k\pi)i}
$$
So, you have that,
$$\LARGE
z^e = e^{(\pi + 2k\pi)i}
$$
And so,

$$\LARGE
z =  e^{\frac{(\pi + 2k\pi)i}{e}}
$$

Comment: Welcome to this community and great first answer! I see that you have a promising future here :)

Comment: Typo: It's "$2 \cdot k \cdot \pi$" and not "$2 \cdot \pi$" in the first two equations.

Comment: Hint: You can write `\cos` for $\cos$ and `\sin` for $\sin$. If you write it like this, the formatting will be nicer. ;)

Comment: @KevinDietrich Yeah thanks, I was a little off

Comment: Ty, this revived my hope

Comment: @stupid13yo you can validate my answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can understand and approach equations of the form $z^{a} = -1 \wedge a \in \mathbb{R}$ in different ways.

---

###### Roots Of Unity

For example, if you square, you get an equation whose solution is the $2 \cdot \left| a \right|$-[Roots Of Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) (iff $a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
z^{a} &= -1 \quad\mid\quad \left( \cdot \right)^{2}\\
\left( z^{a} \right)^{2} &= \left( -1 \right)^{2}\\
z^{2 \cdot a} &= 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

---

###### Trigonometric Function

We know from [Euler's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) ($e^{x \cdot i} = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i$) that we can represent a complex number $z$ in [Polar Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) ($z = \left| z \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right)$). So, with the help of [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) $\left( \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i \right)^{a} = \cos\left( a \cdot x \right) + \sin\left( a \cdot x \right) \cdot i$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
z^{a} &= -1 \tag{polar form}\\
\left( \left| z \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right) \right)^{a} &= -1\\
\left| z \right|^{a} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right)^{a} &= -1\\
\end{align*}
$$

We know that $\left| 1^{x} \right| = 1$, so $\left| z \right|^{a} = \left| - 1 \right| = 1$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| z \right|^{a} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right)^{a} &= -1\\
1 \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right)^{a} &= -1 \tag{De Moivre's Formula}\\
\cos\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i &= -1\\
\end{align*}
$$

Since the imaginary part of one side of the equation must equal the imaginary part of the other side of the equation, and $-1$ has the imaginary part $0$, $\sin\left( \cdot \right) = 0$ must hold. Thus we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\cos\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i &= -1\\
\cos\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i &= -1 + 0 \cdot i\\
\cos\left( a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \right) &= -1 \quad\mit\quad \arccos\left( \cdot \right)\\
a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) &= \arccos\left( -1 \right) \quad\mit\quad \div a\\
\arg\left( z \right) &= \frac{1}{a} \cdot \arccos\left( -1 \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

So via using the [Polar Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) aigen we get:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \arccos\left( -1 \right) \right) + \sin\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \arccos\left( -1 \right) \right) \cdot i\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

---

###### Using Euler's Identity / Complex Exponentials

We know [Euler's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) ($e^{\pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i} = -1 \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z}$) and we know from [Euler's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) ($e^{x \cdot i} = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i$) that we can represent a complex number $z$ in [Polar Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) ($z = \left| z \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) + \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) \cdot i \right)$). Using this we'll get:
$$
\begin{align*}
z^{a} &= -1\\
\left( z \right)^{a} &= -1 \tag{Polar Form}\\
\left( \left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)^{a} &= e^{\pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i}\\
\left( 1 \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)^{a} &= e^{\pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i}\\
\left( e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)^{a} &= e^{\pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i}\\
e^{a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} &= e^{\pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i} \quad\mid\quad \ln\left( \cdot \right)\\
a \cdot \arg\left( z \right) \cdot i &= \pi \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i \quad\mid\quad \div \left( a \cdot i \right)\\
\arg\left( z \right) &= \frac{1}{a} \cdot \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Using [Euler's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) we'll get:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
z &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \right) + \sin\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \right) \cdot i\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

---

###### Plot Of Values Where $a = e$

**From $k = -10$ To $k = +10$:**

[image]
[image]

**From $k = 0$ To $k = 100$:**

[image]
[image]